# Can't launch dialog activity from broadcast receiver while app in backgroung

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to launch an activity from a BroadcastReceiver, but since android 10, it's impossible.

I don't like the solution of using a full-screen intent because it shows a notification
which the user needs to tap to open the activity.

I can also ask for special permission for that, but I prefer to avoid asking permission.

Therefore, I was trying to launch an activity without UI (not calling the setContentView method) and instead showing a dialog.

This is how I declared the activity in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".DialogActivity"  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

This is how I try to launch it from the BroadcastReceiver:

```
Intent testIntent=new Intent(context, DialogActivity.class);
                testIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(testIntent);
```

And this is the activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class DialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Debug", "Checking: DialogActivity.onCreate");

    getWindow().setLayout(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );


    displayAlert();
}

private void displayAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(
            false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
  }

}
```

The thing is that the activity onCreate method is not even been called. I know it because I can't see the log statement in my Logcat. And off course, the dialog is not shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" -- as you noted yourself, "it's impossible". Please use the full-screen notification. Yes, the user has to tap on it. However, it also means that the user can ignore it, if whatever they are doing right now is more important than the triggering event for your notification.

Comment: @CommonsWare I saw on some answers to similar questions that some users suggest that it is possible using dialog, and I see that some apps are doing it.